# Localhost err_connection_reset after install vite-plugin-mkcert

Tags: reactjs, https, vite

After I install vite-plugin-mkcert then I can run HTTPS for Vite project but another project (webpack) can't run in localhost. But it can run by IP (on the network). I'm using Windows 10
Please, somebody, help me fix this problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00XCT.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goazY.jpg)

Remove vite-plugin-mkcert and netsh winsock reset, netsh int ip reset
But still problem